# How to get a GUI on debian 5 on the playstation 2

Tags: debian, gui

So recently I got Debian Lenny running on my PlayStation 2 slim. This by using a guide on this site: [How to install Linux on the Playstation 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344225/how-to-install-linux-on-the-playstation-2?).
The problem is, a command line interface is nice and everything however I like to have the GUI that shows on the Sourceforge page from the guy who made the kernel and ramdisk (kernelloader project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/kernelloader/). On this wiki I see some images of a gui, I think this is NetSurf but I like to have a standard Linux GUI running.
Obviously, it has to be lightweight (32 mb of ram + 4 mb vram lol).

I have already tried some methods of getting gui packages on to the system(obviously all in root), for example `apt-get install xfce` and `apt-get install xserver-xorg-core` , lightdm and gdm. Every time I try this I get an error saying that the package doesn't exist. This shows that the network is properly configurated (I think) as the ps2 can connect to the archive.debian.org server and read the package lists, however, something still seems to be going wrong. Now I am a total Linux noob, so it could be I completely missed some things.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong? I would be very thankful if someone knows.

Comment: The package name should be `xfce4`. Can you try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install xorg xdm xfce4`?

Comment: `apt-cache search xfce` will give you a list of anything related to xfce (in case you are wondering how Freddy knew the package name).  `apt-cache show <package>` will show you details about each package.

Comment: are you talking about running a terminal window? ... GUI could be any program, it does not specifically mean linux terminal window ... the picture on sourceforge appears to be a web browser